# Datepicker set year range to only one year

Tags: jquery, datepicker

Below is my datepicker code

```
$("#DOB").datepicker({ 
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',                
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        maxDate: "-1",
        modal: false,
        constrainInput: true, 
        yearRange: "-"+agee+":+0"}).on("change", function(e) {
            var curDate = $(this).datepicker("getDate");
            var maxDate = new Date();
            maxDate.setDate(maxDate.getDate()); 
            maxDate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0); // clear time portion for correct results
            console.log(this.value, curDate, maxDate);
            if (curDate > maxDate) {
                messagePopup(this.id + " cannot be Future Date");
                $(this).datepicker("setDate", "");
            }
        });
```

Here in **yearRange: "-"+agee+":+0"})** line you can see a varibale agee.

In this variable I get dynamic value and setting the year range. For example agee is 20 then year range set to 1996 to 2016.

But I want to set the year only 1996 in the datepicker, only one 1996 I want to set. How can I do that?

Comment: Your logic is flawed. It's possible for someone who is 20 years old right now to be born in 1995 or 1996. You cannot know which single year to restrict selection to from the age alone

Comment: Ok Thanks for the advice, can I set two years 1995 and 1996 then.